# how to execute an update every 60 seconds in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

how can I execute an update each 60 seconds in libgdx. I have tried this code but actually "counter" becomes 0 directly

public void update(float delta) {

```
    stage.act(delta);
    counter-=Gdx.graphics.getRawDeltaTime();;
   if (counter==3)
    {   stage.addActor(oneImg);
    }
    else if(counter==2)
    {
        stage.addActor(twoImg);

    }
    else if(counter==1)
    {   stage.addActor(splashImg);
    }


}
```

Comment: Never use `==` with a float or double against a constant besides 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this will happen.

That's because getRawDelta time method of libgdx returns values in floats. When you deduct them from your counter, you might never end up with a perfectly rounded up number like 1, 2, 3.

So just to give you an example, let's say your counter was 3.29 and getRawDeltaTime returned you 0.30..

If you deduct it from 3.29, you will end up with 2.99 and hence you will never hit your if statement.

The way I would do this is

```
counter -= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

if(counter <= 3 && counter > 2) {   
    stage.addActor(oneImg);
} else if(counter <= 2 && counter > 1) {
    stage.addActor(twoImg);
} else if(counter <= 1 && counter > 0)  {
    stage.addActor(splashImg);
}
```

I hope the solution above makes sense.

Also 1 thing to point out which I left in the solution. Every if condition will execute multiple times not just once in my solution.

This is because when you have lets say `(counter <= 3 && counter > 2)`, the counter will have values like 2.9, 2.87, .... i.e. till the time its between 2 and 3.
To fix this you will need to use some booleans.

Define class level `boolean condition1, condition2, condition3;`

Modify the if statement to be like

```
if(counter <= 3 && counter > 2 && !condition1) {   
    stage.addActor(oneImg);
    condition1 = true;
} else if(counter <= 2 && counter > 1 && !condition2) {
    stage.addActor(twoImg);
    condition2 = true;
} else if(counter <= 1 && counter > 0 && !condition3)  {
    stage.addActor(splashImg);
    condition3 = true;
}
```